# object variable not set error in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I had a VBA script in Excel that used to work in an older version of Excel.
However same set of codes does not work in Excel 2010 and gives the following error:

> object variable or with block variable not set error

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and where do I need to amend it?

**Codes as follows:**

```
Sub ExtractCustomerInfo_Click()

    Dim int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer
    Dim strCheck As String, strPreAmount As String
    Dim strAcctno As String
    Dim obal As String
    Dim strAddr1 As String, strAddr2 As String, strAddr3 As String, strAddr4 As String
    Dim strAddr5 As String, strAddr6 As String, strStatus As String, strArm As String, strRto As String
    Dim retval As Long, strValidateLogin  As String
    Dim strUserID As String, strUserPWD As String
    Dim custName As String, custID As String, dump As String
    Dim homeNumber As String, mobileNumber As String, officeNumber As String
    Dim one As String, two As String, three As String, four As String, five As String

    '********** Clear previous results fields
    PcommC 'Call the global function before you do anything
    Sheets("Accounts").Select

    '********* Clear/start variables

    strAddr1 = ""
    strAddr2 = ""
    strAddr3 = ""
    strAddr4 = ""
    strAddr5 = ""
    strAddr6 = ""
    strArm = ""
    strRto = ""
    strAcctno = ""
    addressRow = 0
    custName = ""
    custID = ""
    dump = "a"
    int1 = 6
    one = ""
    two = ""
    three = ""
    four = ""
    five = ""
    officeNumber = ""
    mobileNumber = ""
    homeNumber = ""

    PS(1).SendKeys "2", 23, 13
    PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"
    retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
    PS(1).SendKeys "22", 20, 7
    PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"
    retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
    PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"
    PS(1).SendKeys "2", 20, 7
    retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
    PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"

    Do While IsEmpty(Sheets("Accounts").Range("A" & int1).Value) = False
        DoEvents

        If IsEmpty(Sheets("Accounts").Range("B" & int1).Value) = True Then
            strAcctno = Sheets("Accounts").Range("A" & int1).Value

            '****** Clear search fields
            IA(1).WaitForInputReady
            PS(1).SendKeys "[pf5]"
            retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)

            '**** input search criteria
            IA(1).WaitForInputReady
            PS(1).SendKeys strAcctno, 5, 60
            PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"

            retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
            dump = PS(1).GetText(13, 8, 15)
            dump = Trim(dump)

            If Not dump = "" Then
                retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
                PS(1).SendKeys "6", 13, 3
                PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"

                retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
                PS(1).SendKeys "3", 10, 2
                PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"

                retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)

                custName = PS(1).GetText(3, 12, 40)
                custName = Trim(custName)
                Sheets("Accounts").Range("B" & int1).Value = custName

                custID = PS(1).GetText(4, 12, 25)
                custID = Trim(custID)
                Sheets("Accounts").Range("C" & int1).Value = custID

                one = PS(1).GetText(10, 6, 2)
                one = Trim(one)
                two = PS(1).GetText(12, 6, 2)
                two = Trim(two)
                three = PS(1).GetText(14, 6, 2)
                three = Trim(three)
                four = PS(1).GetText(16, 6, 2)
                four = Trim(four)
                five = PS(1).GetText(18, 6, 2)
                five = Trim(five)

                'One
                If one = "PH" Then
                    homeNumber = PS(1).GetText(10, 10, 30)
                    homeNumber = Trim(homeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("D" & int1).Value = homeNumber
                End If
                If one = "PO" Then
                    officeNumber = PS(1).GetText(10, 10, 30)
                    officeNumber = Trim(officeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("F" & int1).Value = officeNumber
                End If
                If one = "PM" Then
                    mobileNumber = PS(1).GetText(10, 10, 30)
                    mobileNumber = Trim(mobileNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("E" & int1).Value = mobileNumber
                End If

                'Two
                If two = "PH" Then
                    homeNumber = PS(1).GetText(12, 10, 30)
                    homeNumber = Trim(homeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("D" & int1).Value = homeNumber
                End If
                If two = "PO" Then
                    officeNumber = PS(1).GetText(12, 10, 30)
                    officeNumber = Trim(officeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("F" & int1).Value = officeNumber
                End If
                If two = "PM" Then
                    mobileNumber = PS(1).GetText(12, 10, 30)
                    mobileNumber = Trim(mobileNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("E" & int1).Value = mobileNumber
                End If

                'Three
                If three = "PH" Then
                    homeNumber = PS(1).GetText(14, 10, 30)
                    homeNumber = Trim(homeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("D" & int1).Value = homeNumber
                End If
                If three = "PO" Then
                    officeNumber = PS(1).GetText(14, 10, 30)
                    officeNumber = Trim(officeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("F" & int1).Value = officeNumber
                End If
                If three = "PM" Then
                    mobileNumber = PS(1).GetText(14, 10, 30)
                    mobileNumber = Trim(mobileNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("E" & int1).Value = mobileNumber
                End If

                'Four
                If four = "PH" Then
                    homeNumber = PS(1).GetText(16, 10, 30)
                    homeNumber = Trim(homeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("D" & int1).Value = homeNumber
                End If
                If four = "PO" Then
                    officeNumber = PS(1).GetText(16, 10, 30)
                    officeNumber = Trim(officeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("F" & int1).Value = officeNumber
                End If
                If four = "PM" Then
                    mobileNumber = PS(1).GetText(16, 10, 30)
                    mobileNumber = Trim(mobileNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("E" & int1).Value = mobileNumber
                End If

                'Five
                If five = "PH" Then
                    homeNumber = PS(1).GetText(18, 10, 30)
                    homeNumber = Trim(homeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("D" & int1).Value = homeNumber
                End If
                If five = "PO" Then
                    officeNumber = PS(1).GetText(18, 10, 30)
                    officeNumber = Trim(officeNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("F" & int1).Value = officeNumber
                End If
                If five = "PM" Then
                    mobileNumber = PS(1).GetText(18, 10, 30)
                    mobileNumber = Trim(mobileNumber)
                    Sheets("Accounts").Range("E" & int1).Value = mobileNumber
                End If
            Else
                custName = "No matching customer found"
                Sheets("Accounts").Range("B" & int1).Value = custName
            End If
        End If

        dump = "a"
        int1 = int1 + 1
        one = ""
        two = ""
        three = ""
        four = ""
        five = ""
        officeNumber = ""
        mobileNumber = ""
        homeNumber = ""
        PS(1).SendKeys "[pf12]"
        retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
        PS(1).SendKeys "[pf12]"
        retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
    Loop

    PS(1).SendKeys "[pf12]"
    retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
    PS(1).SendKeys "[pf12]"
    retval = PS(1).WaitForCursor(3, 12, 800, False)
    PS(1).SendKeys "90", 20, 7
    PS(1).SendKeys "[enter]"

    MsgBox "Extraction Completed."

End Sub
```

Pcomm Code:

```
'--------PCommC Info---------
Global PS(1 To 6) As AutPS
Global IA(1 To 6) As AutOIA
Global PSa As AutPS
Global PSb As AutPS
Global PSc As AutPS
Global PSd As AutPS
Global PSe As AutPS
Global PSf As AutPS

Global IAa As AutOIA
Global IAb As AutOIA
Global IAc As AutOIA
Global IAd As AutOIA
Global IAe As AutOIA
Global IAf As AutOIA

Global i01 As Integer
Global i02 As Integer

Global SessionList As New AutConnList
Global TotalInfo

Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long

Function PcommC()
On Error Resume Next
DoEvents
Dim ConLetter(1 To 6)
ConLetter(1) = "A"
ConLetter(2) = "B"
ConLetter(3) = "C"
ConLetter(4) = "D"
ConLetter(5) = "E"
ConLetter(6) = "F"

For i01 = 1 To 6
Set IA(i01) = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PS(i01) = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
Next i01

Set SessionList = New AutConnList

For i02 = 1 To SessionList.count
PS(i02).SetConnectionByName (ConLetter(i02))
IA(i02).SetConnectionByName (ConLetter(i02))
Next i02

Set IAa = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PSa = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
Set IAb = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PSb = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
Set IAc = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PSc = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
Set IAd = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PSd = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
Set IAe = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PSe = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
Set IAf = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PSf = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")

IAa.SetConnectionByName ("A")
PSa.SetConnectionByName ("A")
IAb.SetConnectionByName ("B")
PSb.SetConnectionByName ("B")
IAc.SetConnectionByName ("C")
PSc.SetConnectionByName ("C")
IAd.SetConnectionByName ("D")
PSd.SetConnectionByName ("D")
IAe.SetConnectionByName ("E")
PSe.SetConnectionByName ("E")
IAf.SetConnectionByName ("F")
PSf.SetConnectionByName ("F")

End Function
```

Comment: where does the error occur?

Comment: try using 'Set' for making the variables null....

Comment: What's PcommC?  Show some code for the function please.  Otherwise you code doesn't compile.

Comment: Updated with pcomm codes. The error comes about at  the line PS(1).SendKeys "2", 23, 13